# How to get minimized window's RESTORED bounds?

Tags: windows, interop, user32

It's easy to get the bounding rectangle for all the visible windows on a screen. It's also easy to tell if any window is iconic or not.

But for minimized windows, the Top and Left is reported as -32000 from User32.GetWindowInfo.rcWindow. I've looked all through the API and can't find a call to return the bounds the window would restore to if it were clicked on or switched to.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out User32.GetWindowPlacement

Comment: Seems to work great thanks... except for some owner drawn windows like WinAmp, which reports its bounds as {X=3806,Y=-30000,Width=4081,Height=-29884}

Any idea how to get the actual bounds for it?

Comment: Hm, check for 'impossible' values and call GetWindowRect/send WM_NCCALCSIZE is the only solution that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

For C/C++:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
::ZeroMemory(&wp, sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
::GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &wp);
```